# continue message flow after exception on java side

Tags: exception, routes, apache-camel

I'm just trying, to continue processing a message after an exception occurred. I know, that it's possible to use the '<'continued'>'..'<'/continued>' statement from xml, but I want to hide the complexity in the xml document. And don't want to change every module we build so far. Therefore I want to set it via java on a central place.

The case:
If an exception occur, a java bean will be called from the onException block, which analyses the exception and checks the type of the exception. Now I want to configure, that if it is an ExampleException, the exception should be ignored and the routing continue. Just simular to handled, which can be set via the ExchangeHelper, but the difference is, that handled is just an simple header and continued not.

Is there a way to set continued with java on the actual exchange object?

Thanks in advance!

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I found the following and will give it a try.

Exception caught = exchange.getException();

```
    // we continue so clear any exceptions
    exchange.setException(null);
    // clear rollback flags
    exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROLLBACK_ONLY, null);
    // reset cached streams so they can be read again
    MessageHelper.resetStreamCache(exchange.getIn());

    // its continued then remove traces of redelivery attempted and caught exception
    exchange.getIn().removeHeader(Exchange.REDELIVERED);
    exchange.getIn().removeHeader(Exchange.REDELIVERY_COUNTER);
    exchange.getIn().removeHeader(Exchange.REDELIVERY_MAX_COUNTER);
    exchange.removeProperty(Exchange.FAILURE_HANDLED);
    // keep the Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT as property so end user knows the caused exception
```